# BigDecimalでの計算精度を保証する方法

Tags: java

ユーザが定義した計算式（**有理数の四則演算のみ**）を解析し、`BigDecimal`を使って計算するプログラムを作っています。
ここで、「計算結果は、小数点以下2桁までが、手計算での結果と一致することを保証する」という要求仕様があります。
正確には、「手計算で小数点以下第3位を四捨五入した値」との一致です。

`BigDecimal`の`divide`メソッドは、`scale`の指定がありますが、上記の結果を保証するためには、都度の除算において、`scale`にどのような値を指定すれば良いのでしょうか？
あるいは、根本的に保証できないのでしょうか？

結論が出ないながらも、自分で考えたことを挙げておきます。

- 「小数点以下第3位を四捨五入」という操作が最後にあるので、結局は3桁目まで正しい状態を維持しなければならない
- `divide`に対して`scale=3`を指定したとしても、`1/3=0.333`を3000倍すると999になってしまう。小数点以下何桁の保証どころではない。

  - `(1/3)*3000` を `3000*1/3`に組み替えるようなことをしないと、根本的に保証できない？
  - あるいは、「**十分に大きな**`scale`を指定しておく」という方針？
  - 例えば`scale=6`としたとき、`1/3=0.333333`、これを3000倍で`999.999`となる。小数点以下第3位を四捨五入すれば、`1000`になる。
  - 「十分に大きなscale」とは何か？　具体的な値を定義できるか？

【追記】

- 「このような計算式なら精度を保証できる」という制限付き仕様は実現可能か？

  - `(a + b) / (x * y)`のように、「除算が高々1回」かつ「除算が最後に実行される形」であれば良い？

Comment: そもそもコンピュータにおける計算で任意の値や計算式に対して「計算結果は、小数点以下2桁までが、手計算での結果と一致することを保証する」という要求自体が無茶だと思います。

Comment: @mok2pok 「計算式」というのは具体的にどういうものなのでしょうか？　有理数の四則演算のみですか？

Comment: @Ripple その可能性を直観的には感じています。ただ数学に疎く、それを証明することができていません。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 質問文に追記します。

Comment: `BigDecimal`で表現できる数での除算の真値はとんでもない桁数で循環する循環小数になりえます。例えば1億桁で循環する循環小数を含む複雑な計算の「手計算での結果」なんてものは定義不可能でしょう。定義不可能なものを「仕様」としてはいけません。また乗数として3000の場合を考えておられますが、`BigDecimal`では、m×10^scale で数値が表現でき、mは任意精度の整数なわけですから、任意の`BigDecimal`が乗数となりうる以上「十分に大きなscale」というものは存在しません。本当に「有理数の四則演算のみ」であれば、`BigDecimal`の演算を使わず有理数演算に置き換えるという手もありますがかなり大変な作業になります。私的には「手計算での結果と一致する」などという曖昧な要求をきちんと現実的な仕様にする(様々なケースを考慮して実際の動作を定義する)ところから始めるべきだと思いますが。

Comment: @mok2pok 厳密な証明は面倒かも知れませんが、簡単に言うと「コンピュータでは無限の精度の数値は扱えない」に尽きるかと思います。で、@OOPerさんのおっしゃる通り、扱える数値の範囲や精度、演算時のオーバーフロー/アンダーフローなどについて仕様を定義する必要があるわけで、BigDecimalを使うのであれば基本的にBigDecimalの制限事項をそのまま仕様とすることになると思います。そしてBigDecimalでは割り算のとき有効桁数を指定する必要があるので、それをその「ユーザーが定義した計算式」の中で何とか表現するようにしてもらうか、例えば10桁とかに決めて「割り算の精度は10桁ですよ」と言い切っちゃうとかですね。

Comment: @OOPer 「手計算での結果」というのは要するに数学的に厳密な解（を四捨五入したもの）ということだと解釈していたのですが、どうでしょうか。そういう意味で「精度」と言うことにすると、元の計算式にシンボリックな変形をすることで計算式の中に除算が高々1回のみ存在する形にできることを使って、ある程度の精度保証はできそうだな〜とか適当に考えていました。

Comment: 追記しました。質問文中にあるような、制限付き仕様ならば、精度保証ができるのでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu , ありうる解釈ではあると思いますし、私のコメントの「有理数演算に置き換える」と言う部分もその解釈に則っています。ただ、有理数の四則演算の結果は(ゼロ除算を除いて)必ず有理数になりますので、「除算が高々1回のみ‌​存在する」なんて難しい条件をつけて数式処理(あなたの言う「シンボリックな変形」)をするよりは、Kohei TAMURA さんの提案されたような有理数演算ライブラリを使用する方がかえって簡単になりそうな気がします。

Comment: @OOPer なんだか話がすれ違って伝わっていない気がしますが、分数のライブラリを使って計算することとシンボリックに計算していくことは今回の場合本質的に等価です。分数として計算していった場合も、最後に1回だけ割り算をして小数の形にしますよね、といったら（多少大雑把ですが）ご理解頂けますでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、理解はしているつもりなのですが。本質的に等価であると言う点に反論しているような内容は私のコメントには存在しないと思っているのですが、どこかに等価ではないと解釈できる部分がありますでしょうか? 私のコメントの後半は、どうせ等価ならどっちが楽か、と言うことを言っています。

Comment: @OOPer さん、等価であることがご理解頂けているならばこちらから特に議論したいことはございません :)

Answer (score 3):

質問の回答にはなりませんが、分数を扱う[`org.apache.commons.math4.fraction.Fraction`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html)を使うことで要求仕様は満たせませんか？

除算があるので、分子と分母を分けて考えた方が(例えば、Fractionのように分子と分母を内部的に持っているクラスを使った方)がいいように思います。

十分に大きな`scale`を指定しても、計算の順序を変えないと

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1).divide(new BigDecimal(3), MathContext.DECIMAL128).multiply(new BigDecimal(3)));
```

が、`0.9999999999999999999999999999999999`になるようなことが起こるので。

Comment: 一応補足しますと、`0.9999999999999999999999999999999999`になっても、最終的に3桁目で四捨五入した結果が`1`ならOKではあります。ただ、このアプローチは「何桁まで保証できる」という仕様にはならなさそうですね。

Comment: 計算の過程で誤差が出ると、「何桁まで保証でき‌​る」と言いづらいですからね。

Comment: @mok2pok さん、元コメントに書いた『「手計算での結‌​果」をどう定義するのか』に関わってくるのですが、厳密値が`0.125`になるような計算も、計算順序によっては「手計算」では、`0.1249999999999999999999999999999999`になることがあります。それを「最終的に3桁目で四‌​捨五入」すると`0.12`、さて、これはOKなのでしょうか?